# Formatting Decimal with 2 places.Problem

Tags: c#

I am using the following to put decimal places when formatting an amount but I am not getting the correct amount when testing with eg 25000 I am expecting 25000.00
but I am getting 25000.

What I am doing wrong?How should I change it?

```
                [TestCase(123.45453, 123.45, 2)]
                [TestCase(125.55453, 125.55, 2)]
                [TestCase(125.55653, 125.56, 2)]
                [TestCase(125.56554, 125.57, 2)]
                [TestCase(25000,25000.00,2)]

  public void MyRoundFunction_returns_amount_with_decimal_places(decimal amountToTest, decimal expected, int decimalPlaces)
                {
                    decimal actual = MyRoundFunction(amountToTest, MidpointRounding.ToEven, decimalPlaces);
                    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
                }


         public static decimal MyRoundFunction(decimal value, MidpointRounding midpointRounding, int decimalPlaces)
                {
                    return Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces, midpointRounding);
                }
```

EDITED:

If you were to format a decimal value whatever the amount would always have 2 decimal even when is something like 25000 and you want 25000.00 or 1234.224543 returns 1234.22 how would you code it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like you're passing in double values instead of decimals. Try this:

```
[TestCase(123.45453m, 123.45m, 2)]
[TestCase(125.55453m, 125.55m, 2)]
[TestCase(125.55653m, 125.56m, 2)]
[TestCase(125.56554m, 125.57m, 2)]
[TestCase(25000m, 25000.00m,2)]
```

It's possible that that won't even build - I wouldn't be surprised if `decimal` values were disallowed in attributes as the CLR doesn't know about them. If that *does* happen, you probably want to change the input to strings, parse them to decimals at the start of the test, and then compare them. You'll need to check that `decimal.Parse` preserves the trailing digits, of course... I *think* it does, but I can't remember for sure offhand.

Others have pointed out the "only round at the point of display, when you convert to a string" possibility - I can't say whether or not that's appropriate in your case. I know that there *is* a difference in representation between 25000m and 25000.00m. Whether you *should* be rounding to a given number of decimals will depend on your business requirements, of course.

Comment: thanks for your reply.Leaving unit test aside for a sec.All I am trying to do is create a function/s that will format my decimal to have only 2 decimal and round it sometimes returning a string given a decimal and sometimes returning a decimal given a decimal .And does not seem to work with a round figure eg 25000 .Should I code my function differently or have 2 overloads.one returning a string and another returning a decimal?Getting confused with formatting now.thanks for any more suggestions

Comment: @user231465: The key word here is *format*. That suggests the result should be a string, definitely **not** a decimal. You can't have overloads which differ only by return type - but if you have one method including the word `Format` in the name which returns a string, you could have another of a different name (if you *really* think it's appropriate) which returns a `decimal`...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Just to make sure I understand what you are suggesting. Convert to a string and format accordingly and then convert it to a decimal when appriopriate.Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @user231465: You should *probably* keep it as a decimal without rounding for as long as possible, and only format at the last possible moment. You almost certainly *shouldn't* be parsing the results of your own formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing formatted values. A `decimal` in itself does not have a format; formatting comes into the picture when you have it represented as a string.

Comment: But there *is* a difference in the bit representation of `25000m` and `25000.00m` (unlike for doubles).

Answer (score 0):

That is because 25000 is equal to 25000.00 so it is trimming the zeros.

I think the issue is misunderstanding of the decimal places parameter here - it is NOT to say how many decimal places should be displayed but used for rounding and maximum number of possible decimal places.

Comment: It's equal in some senses but not all. The two values have different internal representations... and calling `25000m.ToString()` will not give the same result as `25000.00m.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Fredrik is right.

And if you want to represent it as string, you can use the ToString(String format) Method like:

```
decimal number = 1200;
string formatted = number.ToString("#.###,00");
```

or other Formatters (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Need to round and return 2 decimal regardless of the amount.How would you do it?Sometimes I need to convert to a string and sometimes it's already a decimal but needs formatted to have only 2 decimal and rounded

Comment: I think the problem is not with your rounding, its with the comparison afterwards. If you have 2500 and round it to two decimals, it will stay the same: I would suggest in this case to convert both (the input and the expected value) to the formatted string and compare the string then.